# Using grep on a shell output to return a boolean value?

Tags: bash, shell, macos-high-sierra

I am currently working on an extension attribute and I have become stuck. I am trying to use grep to report whether or not certain system options are enabled/disabled on my mac. I am using the following code:

```
 if launchctl print system | grep ‘“com.apple.screensharing” => false' 
 then
   echo "enabled"
 else
   echo "disabled"
 fi
```

I keep getting thrown into a weird quote mode by the terminal and I don't know what I am missing. Is anyone able to help? Thank you!

Comment: `launchctl print system | grep -q '"com.apple.screensharing" => false' && echo "enabled" || echo "disabled"`

Comment: Both your single quotes should be `'` (U+0027), but the first one is `‘` (U+2018).

Comment: Also, the output of `launchctl` uses normal double quotes, you use "smart ones" (`""` vs `“”`).

Comment: You should be careful to edit your scripts with a text editor, not a word processor.

Comment: @anubhava that works perfectly thank you so much! And thank all you guys for the help and quick responses!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an issue of typography, not programming.